# empty files in python

Tags: python, file, text-files

I am trying to create a file with all the magnetic information in my lists. I've used this code before as well. for some reason the file it returns is empty. I'm not sure why.

here is my code:

```
magnetosheath_Bx = JSS_Bx[12339:13795]
magnetosheath_By = JSS_By[12339:13795]
magnetosheath_Bz = JSS_Bz[12339:13795]        
magnetosheath_B = JSS_Bmag[12339:13795]
magnetosheath_time = epochtime_magdata[12339:13795]
magnetosheath_r = new_RJSE[12339:13795]   

Magnetosheath_data = zip(magnetosheath_Bx, magnetosheath_By, magnetosheath_Bz, magnetosheath_B, magnetosheath_time, magnetosheath_r)


filenew= open('Ulysses_Magnetoseath.txt' , 'w') 

filenew.write("hello")
for magnetic_data in Magnetosheath_data:
        filenew.write('{}   {}  {}  {}  {}  {}\n'.format(magnetic_data[0], magnetic_data[1], magnetic_data[2], magnetic_data[3],magnetic_data[4],magnetic_data[5] ))
        filenew.write("hello")
```

Comment: By returns empty, do you really mean returns empty? Because you have no returns in your code at all. Do you mean the information written to the file is empty?

Comment: yea. the file is has no data.

Comment: Have you tried closing the file with `filenew.close()`? You can also use `with open('Ulysses_Magnetoseath.txt', 'w') as filenew:` and do whatever you need to do with the file within that block and Python will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: does empty mean you do not have even a single "hello" ?

Comment: print out the len of Magnetosheath_data just to make sure it's not zero